# Read input with commas (with sscanf)

Tags: c, input, scanf

Hi I'm trying to read the input of a user in the following form:

```
param1,param2,param3
```

that I get with `fgets`. The problem is that I can't seem to understand why it doesn't, after the first comma it shows me a weird behaviour.
Ex:

```
char input[60];
char a1, a2, a3, a4;


printf("Enter info");
fgets(input, 60, stdin);
sscanf(input,"%[^,\n] %[^,\n] %[^,\n] %[^,\n]", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);
printf("%c %c %c %c", a1, a2,a3, a4);
```

If I type for example `a,b,c,d`
I get: `a   �`
What am I missing here ?

Comment: `%[...]` will read in a string which will need a closing '\0' char. Make your varaibles to `char a[2]`. Also I think your `sscanf` format string will not match your input so your variables are actually holding some unitialized garbage data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answer. Your format string is missing the actual `,` commas, so `1,2,3,4` cannot match it.

You can do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char input[60];
  char a1[2], a2[2], a3[2], a4[2];


  printf("Enter info");
  fgets(input, 60, stdin);
  if (4 != sscanf(input,"%1[^,\n], %1[^,\n], %1[^,\n], %1[^,\n]", a1, a2, a3, a4))
    return printf("Error"), 1;

  printf("%c %c %c %c", a1[0], a2[0],a3[0], a4[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Note the error checking with `sscanf` if it was successful it should return the number of variables which it filled with data. It must be 4 if it worked.

Change the array size of your parameter and the number after the `%` in the `sscanf` format string to match your needs.

Edit:
To make it throw an error if the input has too much params you can do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char input[60];
  char a1[2], a2[2], a3[2], a4[2];
  char temp[2];

  printf("Enter info");
  fgets(input, 60, stdin);
  if (4 != sscanf(input,"%1[^,\n], %1[^,\n], %1[^,\n], %1[^,\n] %1[^\n]", a1, a2, a3, a4, temp))
    return printf("Error"), 1;

  printf("%c %c %c %c", a1[0], a2[0],a3[0], a4[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

By adding `%1[^\n]` to the end of the format `sscanf` will try to read in another non whitespace character after the four parameter. If it succeed that mean there is too much parameter in the input for ex:`1,2,3,4,5`. It will return 5 which is the number of data it was able to fill. But this last format specifier should not match anything if the input is valid, so `sscanf` should return exactly 4 in case of a valid input.

Comment: your code works fine but the problem is that if I enter a,b,c,d,e it doesn't print an error, only if enter less than 4 args

Comment: @MM1 Edited it to include test for it (not checked but should work)

Comment: It does, do you mind explaining what you did exactly ?

Comment: @MM1 Edited into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `%[` format specifier appends a null character as it consumes a sequence of characters.

It needs to have an appropriate argument of type `char[]` capable of holding at least the character plus the null character, but the relative arguments of each `%[` is only of type `char` at your example.

This is causing undefined behavior, as the appending `\0` is written beyond the bounds of the array.

If you want to read and print comma separated word you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char input[60];
  char a1[15], a2[15], a3[15], a4[15];

  for(int i; i < 10; i++)
  {
      a1[i] = a2[i] = a3[i] = a4[i] = 0;  // Initialize each character with `\0`.
  }

  printf("Enter info\n");
  fgets(input, 60, stdin);
  sscanf(input,"%[^,\n],%[^,\n],%[^,\n],%[^\n]", a1, a2, a3, a4);


  printf("%s %s %s %s", a1, a2, a3, a4);
  return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
/a.out
hello,mister,tamborine,man
hello mister tamborine man
```